# Element.GetCilentRects() Does Not Return Object In Collapsed CRM Section Contents

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dynamics-crm-2011

In IE9+, I am using the below code in order to get the "height" of a page's contents, which are rendered inside an Iframe, which is nested inside another Iframe.  All of that is hosted inside of a CRM Section in Dynamics 2011. (I know it is not a desirable design, but I cannot change that without a rewrite of our current project.)

```
var hgt = element.getClientRects().top() + 60;
setIframeHeight(iFrameId, hgt);
```

When I collapse or open a Section, it should return an object containing a property "top" for a custom DOM element at the bottom of our HTML, per calls to the method containing the above code during **tabStateChange**.  In Chrome, I get the same value when opening or collapsing the Section.

However, although opening a section works identically in IE, when I am collapsing the Section, it returns only the base object (proto properties) that is returned from the Element.getClientRects() call, but not the object property which should contain the values.

Is there a different call that I should be using for this functionality so that both Chrome and IE have the same behavior?  Or perhaps there is a trick to making IE "see" the boundaries of the visible objects within a collapsed CRM section?  Note that I am limited to using native JavaScript for the resizing operation, so utilizing frameworks like jQuery is not possible.